# How to calculate a Root-mean-square deviation weighted so that it will take less into account the points that have big error bars

Tags: python, statistics, weighted, errorbar

I want to calculate a Root-mean-square deviation but I need to weight it so that it will take less into account the points that have big error bars.
My tutor calls it a scatter, but I think this is what he means.

This is my code so far:

```
N_x=np.sum(1.5-d_x/(np.max(d_x)))/len(d_x) 
N_y=np.sum(1.5-d_y/(np.max(d_y)))/len(d_y)
N=N_x*N_y 
Sigma=(1.5-d_x/(np.max(d_x)))*(1.5-d_y/(np.max(d_y)))*((ydata-yfit)**2)*N 
sig.append(np.sqrt(np.mean(Sigma)))
```

And it works but it seems a bit arbitrary, since I've chosen 1.5. If I replace 1.5 by 2, or by 1, the scatter really changes and it is not likely anymore.

I've tried to do a method where I take the smallest residual with a code like this:

```
def sigma(x,y,dx,b):
     y1=lin(x-dx,b)
     y2=lin(x+dx,b)
     if y1<=y<=y2:
         return(0)
     else:
         return(np.minimum((y-y1)**2,(y-y2)**2))
```

But it gives really small scatters.